# return component with hook in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have 2 components. I want to keep component A clean, hence I don't wish to use useState in it, I wish to use useState in component B, but since the component B isn't a hook (because it return the jsx as well), how can I call stateHandler in component A?

```
const ComponentA = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentB />
        <button onClick={()=>{
          //what to do here to control the state of component B?
        }}>show component B</button>
      </div>
    )
}

const ComponentB = () => {
  //I don't want to move this setShowBlock to index.js for clean code purpose
  const [showBlock, setShowBlock] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div>
      {showBlock && <div>component B</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ggtt87?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

you can use context as central store,
in the context you create the useState hook with showBlock and setShowBlock  and then you can change it from component A

```
const ComponentA = () => {
        const {setShowBlock} = useContext(MyContext)
        return (
          <div>
            <ComponentB />
            <button onClick={()=>{
              here call setShowBlock and change it 
            }}>show component B</button>
          </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: context for 2 simple component?

Comment: it doesn't have to be a context i'm talking about real use case not just two components ... 
if you want to pass the state between two components without using parent child between them you can add another component let's say App.js and use it as a parent for both then you can pass state between them using your scénario,

Comment: can you show a working code? I have demo above. if you can't solve my problem I think you understood my question wrongly.